# JQuery Autocomplete on .NetCore 2 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-autocomplete, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on an autocomplete that calls a method on my home controller, the javascript calls the method and returns the array. However the values do not display on the text box drop down, nothing does.

If I use a straight array as the source and don't call the home controller then it works just fine.

I don't see what I'm missing here, so I narrowed down the home controller method just to return an array using no logic until I figure this problem out.

Home Controller Method:

```
public string[] GetPatientName()
{
      var names = new List<string> { "Bent","Boon","Book", "Al", "Cat", "Doe", "Ed", "Fox", "George" };

      return names.ToArray();
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetPatientName",
                    data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d,
                        function (item) {
                            alert(item);
                            return { value: item }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            delay: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="tags" type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:
1. From the top of my mind, if it wirked with a regular array and didnt work with the result of jQuery map function you probably need to ad .get() in order to get a clean array. To be precise

```
$.map(data.d,function (item) {
                              alert(item);
                               return { value: item }
                             }).get();
```

2. If that doesnt work, you would really have to share more data like what is the "response" function and exactly what response you are getting from the server (you could get that from the web browser's dev tools)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success ((index):63)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)` error using the code `success: function (data) {
                        $.map(data.d,function (item) {
                            alert(item);
                            return { value: item }
                        }).map();
                    }`

Comment: I got it working from this article. I just returned JSON instead of an array https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ui-autocomplete/